# How to grant disk access permission automator quick action

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, automator, permission

I have an Automator quick action which, among other things, calls the shell command `xxd` in order to perform a hexdump. I am outputting the hex to a file in my home directory. When I execute the quick action within Automator, everything works as expected and a file appears in my directory with the contents of the hexdump. However, when I export the quick action and then execute it as a Finder "service," it fails with the error message: *xxd: Read-only File System*. Similar attempts using the more standard `echo` command to write to a file produce the same error. I assume that my quick action inherits the permissions of the application from which is it executed. However, I have granted Finder "Full Disk Access" permission, as well as every other permission I can think of in the Privacy system preferences pane.

How can I further trace what is causing this permission failure?

Comment: How are you specifying your home directory, as `~/` or as a full path `/Users/yourname/`?

Comment: I was inadvertently passing an AppleScript path to ```xxd```, which goes all the way back to ```Macintosh HD```. Casting my path ```as POSIX path``` fixed the problem because it trims the path down to ```/Users/myname/...```. The hard disk being read-only presumably caused this error, right?  Thanks for your help, @ lx07!

Comment: Yes - if it was trying to write to [somewhere here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650) you'd get the *Read only filesystem* error.  The *Full Disk Access* and other Privacy pane permissions apply to limiting apps access to Documents, Pictures, external drives and so on.